# Parsing JSON from server using EXTjs4

Tags: extjs4

i am getting problem in parsing JSON which starts as `[{....}]` this while i am able to parse JSON of format `{"Ex"[{........}] }`
and please resolve my problem

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
type:'jsonp',
url: '  x/y/z       ',
method:'POST',
callbackkey:'callback',
params:{
format:'json'
},
callback:function (response, value, request) { 
var localdata = JSON.stringify(value);
localStorage.setItem('ProjectDetailsJS', localdata);
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('ProjectDetails');
console.log("List are"+localdata);
alert('Success')
},
failure:function (response, request) {
alert('failure') 
},
error:function(){
alert('error')
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you read the documentation about JSONP. It requires the resulting data to be wrapped in a function. There are examples here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP